# Why does my code stop compiling?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, compilation

For some reason I'm having a difficult time getting this one part of my code to compile.  What we're supposed to do in this section is create a an option to buy and sell stock.  The user will input a "B" "b" to buy or "S" "s" to sell.  The issue I'm having is my code stops before it accepts the users choice to buy or sell.  It prints all the way up to "Enter Option:" then stops.

Stock Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TradeStock
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {

        //declarations
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          String name;  //Name of stock
          String symbol, decision;  //Symbol of stock
          double price; //price per share of stock
          int    shares;    //number of shares of stock

          Stock myStock = new Stock();

        //Get name and symbol
          System.out.print("Enter name of stock: ");
          name = in.nextLine( );
          if(!myStock.setName(name))
          {
             System.out.println("Invalid Name - Must have at least one character");
             System.exit(0);
          }


          System.out.print("Get symbol of stock: ");
          symbol = in.nextLine( );
          if(myStock.setSymbol(symbol))
          {
             myStock.setSymbol(symbol);
          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println("Invalide Symbol of stock - Must be between 3 and 6 characters, inclusively");
             System.exit(0);
          }


        //create Stock object with price and symbol
          Stock myNames = new Stock(name, symbol);

        //prompt user for price and set it
          System.out.print("Enter price of stock: ");
          price = in.nextDouble( );
          myStock.setPrice(price);
          if(myStock.setPrice(price))
          {
             myStock.setPrice(price);
          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println("Invalid Price - Must be greater than 0");
             System.exit(0);
          }

        //prompt user for number of shares and set it
          System.out.print("Enter number of shares: ");
          shares = in.nextInt( );
          myStock.setShares(shares);
          if(myStock.setShares(shares))
          {
             myStock.setShares(shares);
          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println("Invalid number of Shares Must be between 10 and 1000, inclusively and a multiple of 10");
             System.exit(0);
          }
        //print all stock information
        //uses space needed for each output value
          System.out.printf("%nName:   %s%n" ,myStock.getName());
          System.out.printf("Symbol: %s%n"  , myStock.getSymbol());
          System.out.printf("Price:  %.2f%n", myStock.getPrice());
          System.out.printf("Shares: %d%n"  , myStock.getShares());

          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("Options as single upper or lower case character:");
          System.out.println("    B to buy the stock");
          System.out.println("    S to sell the stock");
          System.out.println("    Any other to exit");

          System.out.println("Enter Option: ");
          decision = in.nextLine();

          if(decision.equals("B") || decision.equals("b"))
          {
             System.out.println("Cost of shares: " + myStock.calcValue());
             System.out.println("Commission: " + myStock.calcCommission());
             System.out.println("Total Cost: " + (myStock.calcValue() + myStock.calcCommission()));
          }
          else
             if(decision.equals("S") || decision.equals("s"))
             {
                System.out.println("Receipts: " + myStock.calcValue());
                System.out.println("Commission: " + myStock.calcCommission());
                System.out.println("Net Receipts: " + (myStock.calcValue() + myStock.calcCommission()));
             }

       }
    }
```

Test class
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class TradeStock
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

    //declarations
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name;  //Name of stock
      String symbol, decision;  //Symbol of stock
      double price; //price per share of stock
      int    shares;    //number of shares of stock

      Stock myStock = new Stock();

    //Get name and symbol
      System.out.print("Enter name of stock: ");
      name = in.nextLine( );
      if(!myStock.setName(name))
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid Name - Must have at least one character");
         System.exit(0);
      }


      System.out.print("Get symbol of stock: ");
      symbol = in.nextLine( );
      if(myStock.setSymbol(symbol))
      {
         myStock.setSymbol(symbol);
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Invalide Symbol of stock - Must be between 3 and 6 characters, inclusively");
         System.exit(0);
      }


    //create Stock object with price and symbol
      Stock myNames = new Stock(name, symbol);

    //prompt user for price and set it
      System.out.print("Enter price of stock: ");
      price = in.nextDouble( );
      myStock.setPrice(price);
      if(myStock.setPrice(price))
      {
         myStock.setPrice(price);
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid Price - Must be greater than 0");
         System.exit(0);
      }

    //prompt user for number of shares and set it
      System.out.print("Enter number of shares: ");
      shares = in.nextInt( );
      myStock.setShares(shares);
      if(myStock.setShares(shares))
      {
         myStock.setShares(shares);
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid number of Shares Must be between 10 and 1000, inclusively and a multiple of 10");
         System.exit(0);
      }
    //print all stock information
    //uses space needed for each output value
      System.out.printf("%nName:   %s%n" ,myStock.getName());
      System.out.printf("Symbol: %s%n"  , myStock.getSymbol());
      System.out.printf("Price:  %.2f%n", myStock.getPrice());
      System.out.printf("Shares: %d%n"  , myStock.getShares());

      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Options as single upper or lower case character:");
      System.out.println("    B to buy the stock");
      System.out.println("    S to sell the stock");
      System.out.println("    Any other to exit");

      System.out.println("Enter Option: ");
      decision = in.nextLine();

      if(decision.equals("B") || decision.equals("b"))
      {
         System.out.println("Cost of shares: " + myStock.calcValue());
         System.out.println("Commission: " + myStock.calcCommission());
         System.out.println("Total Cost: " + (myStock.calcValue() + myStock.calcCommission()));
      }
      else
         if(decision.equals("S") || decision.equals("s"))
         {
            System.out.println("Receipts: " + myStock.calcValue());
            System.out.println("Commission: " + myStock.calcCommission());
            System.out.println("Net Receipts: " + (myStock.calcValue() + myStock.calcCommission()));
         }

   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: Do you realize that that part of the code is prompting the user for input?  The code won't advance until the user types something and presses enter.

Comment: It's strange because it compiles without an error, it just stops before accepting the users decision to buy or sell, but prints "Enter Option:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes in your code

```
System.out.print("Enter number of shares: ");
      shares = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); // insted of in.nextInt()
```

or do `in.skip("\n");` after `in.nextInt();`.

Because you are doing this after these line :-

```
 System.out.println("Enter Option: ");
      decision = in.nextLine();
```

which accepts a `\n` for termination of reading which was left by `in.nextInt()` in the input stream.

After looking your code, I think you should use `in.skip("\n")` because you are doing `nextDouble()` before `nextInt()`. Both will left the `\n` in the Input stream.

When you do `nextInt()` you enter your data as follows : `123` enter.

`nextInt()` reads only `123` but enter(`\n`) still remains in you stream.

`nextLine()` requires a `\n` for reading a data which is given by enter.

So when you are reading you next input with `nextLine()`, `\n` (enter) was already present in the stream. Thats why your next input was not read.

So for reading you next data you must skip that `\n` from the input stream.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I don't mean to ask too much, but if you could explain the in.skip("\n"); with a little more detail I would really appreciate it.  I was able to get my code to work, but I'm not fully understanding what it did.  From what I get my previous code was accepting a line previously executed before the scanner that would accept the decision, and since it read something before it wouldn't execute the if statements because it wouldn't have been an S or B.  Sorry  if I'm completely off.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will immediatelly quit if the user enters anything except a "s" or "b", including a newline. The input stream will most probably contain a newline from the previous prompt at this time. Make sure `decision` is valid before you execute the last if.

Answer (score 0):

```
shares = in.nextInt( );
decision = in.nextLine();
```

scanner.nextInt() takes only integer value(doesn't read next tokens), if you are entering integer(24) and "Enter", shares variable gets assigned to 24 and decision gets assigned to "\n" since you clicked "Enter" after integer 24. Which is the reason we suggest to use in.skip("\n") so that it ignores next new line character after integer.

Please add one more else statement to decision block to watch how your code is working:

```
else
         if(decision.equals("S") || decision.equals("s"))
         {
            System.out.println("Receipts: " + myStock.calcValue());
            System.out.println("Commission: " + myStock.calcCommission());
            System.out.println("Net Receipts: " + (myStock.calcValue() + myStock.calcCommission()));
         }else {
   System.out.println("User Input "+decision+" is invalid"); 
}
```

or run in debug mode to watch the value of decision varialbe.